# Custom Button with Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, button, custom-controls

I would like to create a Custon Button in WPF, so I have write this code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RiabilitazioneCognitiva.ButtonPersonalizzati"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="GlassButton.xaml" />
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <Button  x:Name="pippo" Style="{DynamicResource GlassButton}" 
        Click="button_Click">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF"  />

        </StackPanel>
    </Button>


</UserControl>
```

Now i insert this Button in my page, so i  try this code:

```
<Window xmlns:RiabilitazioneCognitiva="clr-namespace:RiabilitazioneCognitiva"  x:Name="framePrincipale" x:Class="RiabilitazioneCognitiva.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RiabilitazioneCognitiva"
        Title="Stop" 
        Height="{Binding}" 
        Width="{Binding}" 
        Background="White" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
</Window>

<Grid>
   <local:ButtonPersonalizzati />
</Grid>
```

It found, but if i insert this i don't see Button

```
<local:ButtonPersonalizzati x:Text="pp" >
```

Can we help me?

Thanks

PS: in ButtonPersonalizzati.cs i have this

```
public string Text { 
   get{return Text;}
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Compile error? Runtime error? Any exception? You need to add more details here.

Comment: I don't have error, exception or runtime error but i don't see the CustomBottm in my Window

Comment: This will throw SO exception becuase of cyclic reference - `public string Text { get{return Text;}}`.

Comment: Ok i change my code, public string Text {get;set;}   . So in the XAML file i have try this <local:ButtonPersonalizzati x:Name="pp" local:Text="Pippo" > but i don't see the string Pippo on button

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set your data context. There are a variety of ways to deal with this, but my typical approach is to do something like this:

```
<UserControl ...
             x:Name="ucThis">
         ...
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ucThis Path=Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF"  />
         ...
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the tag `local:ButtonPersonalizzati`

```
<local:ButtonPersonalizzati x:Name="pp" local:Text="Pippo" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Define `Text` as a DependencyProperty so you can bind to it:

```
public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonPersonalizzati), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

You should also set the DataContext in the constructor of your class:

```
this.DataContext=this;
```

Comment: `foo = "{Binding Path=bar}"` where `bar` is a CLR property (not a dependency property) is perfectly valid and is what the OP is trying to do here.

Comment: it is valid, but useless: it wont reflect the changes of the property